# Paginator on laravel 4.2

Tags: laravel-4

I am new to laravel and I am trying to get a pagination function into my result pages, so I have the following function to generate results from query and I would like to have a pagination on the results page, but I don't seem to get it work correctly

```
public function showResults()
{
     $selectedquery = Input::get('Annonces');
     $what = Input::get('what');    
     $where = Input::get('where');

     $results = DB::table('annonces')->where($selectedquery,'LIKE',      '%'.$what.'%')
                                     ->where('Lieu','LIKE', '%'.$where.'%')
                                     ->get();



    return View::make('results',array('results' => $results));    
    }
```

Any Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for one, you're missing the call to `->paginate(n)`. Right now, your closure is `->get()`, which returns all results for your `annonces` table. This is good, but doesn't work for pagination. Change the function like so:

```
$results = DB::table('annonces')->where($selectedquery,'LIKE',      '%'.$what.'%')
  ->where('Lieu','LIKE', '%'.$where.'%')
  ->paginate(10);
```

This will return all results grouped into 10 results per page. Feel free to change that as you see fit.

Lastly, somewhere on your `view` where you display the results, you will need to use this code to display a page-viewer:

```
<?php echo $results->links(); ?>
<!-- OR -->
{{ $results->links(); }}
```

Also, be sure to check out the docs on Laravel's pagination. You'll find it's pretty comprehensive!

[Laravel Pagination](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/pagination)

Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks for your help, indeed it is puting results 10 per page, but the the {{$results->links();}} not working on the view, it is not showing the links to the other pages.

Comment: Are you getting some kind of error? *Not working* can mean a lot of different things :P

Comment: Also, do you have more than 10 results? Because if you don't, there aren't going to be any more pages to display.

Comment: nothing on the log, and the page is diplaying the first 10 results but no way to go the second page since no pagination buttons are present, and I can't see the div I created for the links blade function.

Comment: my mistake, I was working on a a copy of the view and not the view itself, now it is showing. thanks, I will test it further.

Comment: Hi sorry to bother you again, but the links are not pointing to the next page at all and they are coming back to the search page. any idea?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, check how your routes are set up, make sure your not redirecting somewhere on a `get` request, as the paginator uses `/route?page=2` for every page. Other than that, hard to tell without seeing controller, `routes.php` and view files.